# Live CD with Casper partition problem

Tags: 14.10

I'm using Ubuntu Live CD on version 14.10. I'm already tired of creating a casper-rw block file for each time i mess everything up (It takes a lot of time to generate a new 4GB one).

So, i went to the option of creating a casper partition.

After resizing the drive (An 8GB Sandisk Cruzer Blade) to about 1.2G i went on and created an EXT2 partition named `casper-rw` with the space left. Rebooted the system as i was ordered. No success, Ubuntu doesn't see the partition the way it should.

Tried again with en EXT4 partition, same result.

Am i missing something?

Here's my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're booting from the usb, and the Ubuntu iso is in sdb1? Or if you're using an actual cd things may be different, but for all on the usb:

Apparently Ubuntu may use an existing casper-rw file on the "main" partition (sdb1) first, did you try renaming or deleting the casper-rw file (after backing it up or any data on it you want) and then rebooting? Then it should try using the casper-rw partition.

I expected you'd have to edit some boot parameters to tell Ubuntu which casper-rw to use, like if you wanted to have it on a hard drive or other external drive, but I didn't find any ways to do that (yet), anyone else know?

Comment: Like i said, everything, including the boot partition is on the USB flash drive. No casper block was created this time. As you can see, the partition is seen as a "Logic" partition, so it's showing here on the bottom left.

Comment: By the way, thanks to KasiyA for editing the question to put the image, Ask wasn't letting me do so.

Comment: If there's no other casper-rw files anywhere, and if Ubuntu's booting with the "persistent" option, then from what I've read it _should_ work... (Note: should != will ;)

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the command line at the bootup.

Comment: That's what the "persistent" option is, added to the "`linux ... initrd=... noeject noprompt --`" line, should have `persistent` in there before, like the `--` is fine. If you're already creating new casper-rw files regularly I assumed you have `persistent` in there already. I thought it would have to be changed to find the casper-rw file too, but apparently it just looks in a few places for an existing file or partition first.